# how to post ticker on facebook with opengraph on android without "music.listens" define tag

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, ticker

I'm trying to post tickers on Facebook with open graph on Android, I used at 1st the defined action types 'Listen' (set by Facebook), but this one can only be used by Facebook partners :

**Feedback from your most recent submission:
General
To access the listen action, you must have the appropriate relationships in place with rights owners. However, we're not currently accepting new submissions.**

code I used for this :

```
public void sendListenTicker(PlayElement a_element) {

    if(requestPublishPermissions() == false) {
        return;
    }

    // Create a batch request
    RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();

    // Set up the OpenGraphObject representing the book.
    OpenGraphObject song = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("music.song");
    song.setTitle(a_element.titre);
    song.setDescription(a_element.artiste);
    song.setUrl(a_element.url);
    song.setImageUrls(Arrays.asList(a_element.getPochette()));

    // Create the request for object creation
    // Set up the object request callback
    Request.Callback objectCallback = new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            // Log any response error
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FB error " + error.getErrorMessage());
                Log.d(TAG, " - " + error);

                Request.Callback objectCallbackDelete = new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        // Log any response error
                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        if (error != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "FB error " + error.getErrorMessage());
                            Log.d(TAG, " - " + error);
                        }

                        _radioID = "";
                        _preferences.edit().putString("RADIO_TICKER_ID", _radioID).commit();
                    }
                };

                Request objectDelete = Request.newDeleteObjectRequest(_session, _radioID, objectCallbackDelete);
                RequestBatch requestBatchDelete = new RequestBatch();
                requestBatchDelete.add(objectDelete);
                requestBatchDelete.executeAsync();
            }
        }
    };

    Request objectRequest;

    if( !_radioID.equalsIgnoreCase("") ) {
        song.setId(_radioID);
        objectRequest = Request.newUpdateOpenGraphObjectRequest(_session, song, objectCallback);

        // Set the batch name so you can refer to the result
        // in the follow-on publish action request
        objectRequest.setBatchEntryName("objectUpdate");
    } else {
        objectRequest = Request.newPostOpenGraphObjectRequest(_session, song, objectCallback);

        // Set the batch name so you can refer to the result
        // in the follow-on publish action request
        objectRequest.setBatchEntryName("objectCreate");
    }

    // Add the request to the batch
    requestBatch.add(objectRequest);

    if( _radioID.equalsIgnoreCase("") ) {
        // Request: Publish action request
        // --------------------------------------------
        OpenGraphAction readAction = OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost("music.listens");
        // Refer to the "id" in the result from the previous batch request
        readAction.setProperty("song", "{result=objectCreate:$.id}");
        //readAction.setExplicitlyShared(true);

        // Set up the action request callback
        Request.Callback actionCallback = new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error == null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                        _radioID = graphResponse.getString("id");
                        _preferences.edit().putString("RADIO_TICKER_ID", _radioID).commit();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FB error " + error.getErrorMessage());
                    Log.d(TAG, " - " + error);
                }
            }
        };

        // Create the publish action request
        Request actionRequest = Request.newPostOpenGraphActionRequest(_session, readAction, actionCallback);

        // Add the request to the batch
        requestBatch.add(actionRequest);
    }

    // Execute the batch request
    requestBatch.executeAsync();
}
```

The only other option is to set a custom action types like 'Play' but I have some problem with this solution, I can post object but when I want to transform this object into a Facebook ticker I got lot of error from Facebook :

```
errorCode: 100, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported post request
```

or

```
errorMessage: (#100) Only one of reference objects can be specified for type contactios:play.
```

By advance, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same feedback.

The explanation is this ( from a Developer Support Engineer at Facebook ):

"The music.listen action is currently whitelisted for selected partners. We aren't accepting requests to be whitelisted at this time. If/when we release music.listen we'll announce it on our blog."

Hope it helps.